# postgres case compare string to string

Tags: string, postgresql, select

I have a select with a multiple subselects.

I would like to do a case statement where I compare string to sting. 
For example
from ireport I get as a parameter a schema of database. In case of one schema take one select in case of another take another select

```
  select 
        (select a from b) as one,
        (select case "msp." = "msp" THEN select bla bla bal
       else select bla bla) as two
```

postgres doesn't support this I guess.

I tried to put all smth like

```
  select 
        (select a from b) as one,
        (select case par = "msp" THEN select bla bla bal
       else select bla bla) as two
  from
   (select "msp." as par)
```

but (select "msp." as par ) doesn't work as well. Like SELECT 1+2 as result does. I tried do do smth similar.
any suggestions??

thank you

Comment: What you're trying to do here is really unclear. Are you wanting fuzzy string matching so that "msp." matches "msp"?

Comment: yes, from iReport i send parameter of database schema. and I want that parameter (type string) to be compared so the right select statement in subselect is taken

Answer (score 1):

If you're always going to be matching a string against a string with a . appended then the easiest thing to do is just append the . when comparing. e.g.

```
'foo.' = 'foo' || '.'
```